# Regex, get char after char before char

Tags: regex, vb.net

SAMPLE:

```
[Foo][Bar]Foo bar foo bar: foo; bar: foo bar foo bar __
[Foo][Bar]Foo; bar: foo bar __ foo bar foo bar
[Foo]Foo bar foo bar foo bar: foo __ bar; foo bar __ foo bar
[Bar]Foo; bar; foo
```

For example I have a string format like above.

What I want to ask, how to get the letters after the semicolon `;` (not a space or white space), but before the first colon `:`?

If possible, I would like to mark the letters in one step using regex

The letters I want to get are marked in bold

*As additional information, I want to change the letters to uppercase.

Comment: In the example above yes, but in the original data it could be different.

Comment: Wait a second... Do you only want _one_ letter captured? Not _letters_?

Comment: Something like `;\s*(\w)(?=.*:)`? -- It's not clear from the description why the last line should have matches but not the third `bar:` in the first line, while the second line *matches* the description

Comment: Yes, like the example string that I gave in my question and I have put bold marks on the letters that need to be captured.

Comment: Could you include your current code/regex as well, even if it doesn't work?

Comment: And please explain why you expect `b` and `f` to be captured in `[Bar]Foo; bar; foo`. There's no colon at all in there.

Comment: will you show what characters should be bold in your example

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo Sorry, I forgot about that. In the fourth line there is no colon and it must be included or captured as well. The sentence or words after the first colon are a description or an example, so if there is no colon it means there are no additional examples or descriptions.

Comment: @Espada Ok, then the second regex in my updated answer should work

Comment: @Espada If the second regex I suggested doesn't work, can you please add some example strings to your question where it doesn't work so we get more data to work with?

Comment: @InSync I used this format before <code>.*?;\s*(.)</code> but the first line was captured too, if I use this format <code>.*?;\s*(.)(?=:)</code> it gets an error or doesn't catch anything.

Comment: Really, I would simplify this by cleaning the string in the VB code to remove the first colon and everything after, _before_ sending it through the RegEx._ This allows you to greatly simplify the expression (no backtracking, no alternates, no distinguishing colon from the end of the text) without a lot of complexity or work in the VB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two lookarounds to exclude the surroundings from the characters you want to match:

```
(?<=              # Match something preceded by
  ^[^:]*;\s*      # the start of the line, 0 or more non-colons, a semicolon and any whitespaces
)                 # that is
[^\s:]            # not a colon and not a whitespace
(?=               # which must be followed by
  [^:]*(?:$|:)    # 0 or more non-colons, then either the end of the line or the first colon.
)                 #
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/8ZI7nD/1).

`[^:]`, `;`, `\s` and `[^\s:]` never match a colon, so the colon inside the lookahead matches *iff* it is the first colon of that line. If there is no colon, we simply fallback to the end of the line and therefore allow the main expression to match.

The regex needs to have the multiline modifier (`(?m)`/`RegexOptions.Multiline`). I don't know VB.NET, but the following snippet seems to work:

```vb
Sub Main()
  Dim regex As New Regex("(?<=^[^:]*;\s*)[^\s:](?=[^:]*(?:$|:))", RegexOptions.Multiline)
  Dim input As String =
    "[Foo][Bar]Foo bar foo bar: foo; bar: foo bar foo bar __" & vbCrlf &
    "[Foo][Bar]Foo; bar: foo bar __ foo bar foo bar" & vbCrlf &
    "[Foo]Foo bar foo bar foo bar: foo __ bar; foo bar __ foo bar" & vbCrlf &
    "[Bar]Foo; bar; foo"
  
  Console.WriteLine(regex.Replace(input, AddressOf ConvertToUppercase))
End Sub

Function ConvertToUppercase(match As Match) As String
  Return match.Groups(0).Value.ToUpper()
End Function
```

Try it [on ideone.com](https://ideone.com/WgPqYd).

Comment: At the time of writing, regex101.com returns 504 to most requests, so the link might not be accessible.

Comment: I entered your `(?<=^[^:]*;\s*)[^\s:](?=[^:]*(?:$|:))` manually though and it seems to capture the same things as my `^(?:[^;:]*;\s*(.))+` with the examples OP has given. +1

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thanks. To be honest, I do think that mine is more replace-friendly and therefore more suitable for OP's goal, which is to replace these characters with their uppercased versions.

Comment: No idea. All alternatives that work one way or another are good - and perhaps there's a subtle difference in this that works better for OP. I assume making them uppercase is best done using regular VB functions. I couldn't find anything in the .net regex engine that could do it automatically, but perhaps it's in there somewhere.

Comment: @InSync After 2 days of searching, finally... The regex and vb.net code worked perfectly, just as I expected. Thank you very much :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
^[^;:]*;\s*(.).*:
```

- `^` - start of line anchor
- `[^;:]*` - match on anything but `;` and `:` zero or more times
- `;` - match on a literal `;`
- `\s*` - match of zero or more whitespaces
- `(.)` - capture one character
- `.*` - match on any character zero or more times
- `:` - match on a literal colon

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/7vo1N1/1)

---

Since you also say that you want `b` and `f` captured in `[Bar]Foo; bar; foo`, it doesn't seem like the colon is actually required.

Here's one that'll capture `b` and `f`:

```
^(?:[^;:]*;\s*(.))+
```

- `^` - start of line anchor
- `(?:` - start of non-capturing group

  - `[^;:]*` - match on any character except `;` and `:` zero or more times
  - `;` - match on a literal `;`
  - `\s*` - match on whitespace zero or more times
  - `(.)` - capture one character. Replace with `([^:])` if it's not allowed to be a `:`
- `)` - end of non-capturing group
- `+` - match the non-capturing group 1 time or more

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/b1diUt/1)

Comment: I've tried your code, but as I said, I want to get 1 letter or maybe 1 word (doesn't matter) **after** the semicolon but **before** the first colon. The semicolon after the first colon is not included or considered.

Comment: @Espada Ok, if I understand you correctly, the update should work. There will only be a match on the second line in your example strings.

Comment: I guess OP would like the how word, not just a letter, but letters

Comment: @Jotne That was my first thought but OP don't care if it's just a letter or a word. See the first comment here. Also, in OPs original it was only one letter captured.

Comment: Ok, but there is a bold B in this line as well `[Bar]Foo; bar; foo`, but there are no :, so not sure what is correct.

Comment: @Jotne The original was _[Bar]Foo; **b**ar; **f**oo_. OP has now confirmed that the colon is not required.

Comment: If I am not incorrect, this was posted by OP `[Bar]Foo; **b**ar; **f**oo`

Comment: @Jotne Yes and it was **b** and **f** that was supposed to be captured.  _"The letters I want to get are marked in bold"_ and the double asterisks makes **b** and **f** bold.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I'm confused, if I use the second regex live demo from your answer, I can see it does what I want, but when I try to apply it to the application I'm making (vb.net) it doesn't work. And also when I try again your second regex format in regex101 with the default configuration the fourth line only catches **f**

Comment: @Espada The default configuration is not .net's regex engine so there will differences. You need to use the .net engine. When you say _"it doesn't work"_ - how exactly doesn't it work?